# Normalise a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization, normalize

I have a dataframe named examples with some semantic features occurences:

```
 > str(examples)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    50 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ filename      : chr  "Text01" "Text02" "Text03" "Text04" ...
 $ Control       : num  1 3 0 0 0 6 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ Economic      : num  1 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 2 ...
 $ ExternalVoices: num  1 2 1 1 1 2 1 4 0 1 ...
 $ JobsSkills    : num  0 0 0 0 0 2 0 3 0 0 ...
 $ LegalStatus   : num  0 3 4 0 5 0 1 0 4 0 ...
 $ Modals        : num  4 6 1 5 4 4 2 6 2 2 ...
 $ Orign         : num  2 6 8 6 3 5 3 3 2 6 ...
 $ Sanctions     : num  1 3 0 3 0 3 2 1 1 0 ...
 $ Subjectivisms : num  2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 4 ...
 $ Verbs         : num  3 7 3 11 6 2 7 7 4 5 ...
 $ LineTotal         : num  130 274 258 419 268 210 379 244 172 199 ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   filename = col_character(),
  ..   Control = col_double(),
  ..   Economic = col_double(),
  ..   ExternalVoices = col_double(),
  ..   JobsSkills = col_double(),
  ..   LegalStatus = col_double(),
  ..   Modals = col_double(),
  ..   Orign = col_double(),
  ..   Sanctions = col_double(),
  ..   Subjectivisms = col_double(),
  ..   Verbs = col_double(),
  ..   LineTotal = col_double()
  .. )
```

```
head(examples)
 A tibble: 6 x 12
  filename Control Economic ExternalVoices JobsSkills LegalStatus Modals Orign Sanctions Subjectivisms Verbs LineTotal
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Text01         1        1              1          0           0      4     2         1             2     3   130
2 Text02         3        3              2          0           3      6     6         3             3     7   274
3 Text03         0        0              1          0           4      1     8         0             4     3   258
4 Text04         0        0              1          0           0      5     6         3             4    11   419
5 Text05         0        0              1          0           5      4     3         0             3     6   268
6 Text06         6        0              2          2           0      4     5         3             2     2   210
```

I would need to apply a formula that would multiply the value of each cell by 1000 and divide it by the total of the line, that is, by the column "LineTotal" recursively:

*(cellx1000)/LineTotal*

*LineTotal* changes in each line.

I can't even think of a way to get it done. Any help would be great!

thank you!

**Edit**

Providing the dput(df) for the file to be reproduced:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(filename = c("Text01", "Text02", "Text03", "Text04", 
"Text05", "Text06", "Text07", "Text08", "Text09", "Text10", "Text11", 
"Text12", "Text13", "Text14", "Text15", "Text16", "Text17", "Text18", 
"Text19", "Text20", "Text21", "Text22", "Text23", "Text24", "Text25", 
"Text26", "Text27", "Text28", "Text29", "Text30", "Text31", "Text32", 
"Text33", "Text34", "Text35", "Text36", "Text37", "Text38", "Text39", 
"Text40", "Text41", "Text42", "Text43", "Text44", "Text45", "Text46", 
"Text47", "Text48", "Text49", "Text50"), Control = c(1, 3, 0, 
0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 5, 
5, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 
0, 2, 1, 0, 0), Economic = c(1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 3, 7, 1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), ExternalVoices = c(1, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 8, 6, 2, 0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 
2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 7, 5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 
0, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1), JobsSkills = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), LegalStatus = c(0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 
0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 12, 2, 
0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1, 5, 2, 0, 0, 5, 1, 7, 3, 1, 0), Modals = c(4, 
6, 1, 5, 4, 4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 0, 5, 2, 1, 7, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 
6, 0, 2, 8, 0, 3, 8, 0, 1, 2, 5, 13, 2, 7, 1, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 
5, 8, 5, 0, 2, 7, 1, 3), Orign = c(2, 6, 8, 6, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 
6, 1, 8, 2, 7, 8, 8, 12, 7, 6, 2, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7, 
6, 5, 5, 11, 5, 7, 12, 6, 8, 5, 12, 12, 1, 4, 7, 7, 3, 6, 2, 
3, 5), Sanctions = c(1, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 0, 6, 6, 6, 0, 
2, 4, 1, 4, 9, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1), Subjectivisms = c(2, 
3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 0, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 0, 0, 4, 
3, 2, 6, 5, 0, 4, 10, 4, 2, 0, 7, 3, 6, 3, 2, 6, 4, 7, 6, 1, 
4, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 2, 4), Verbs = c(3, 7, 3, 11, 6, 2, 7, 7, 4, 
5, 1, 9, 6, 7, 10, 6, 11, 7, 7, 2, 2, 8, 5, 8, 7, 8, 2, 6, 6, 
6, 7, 4, 12, 10, 7, 11, 9, 10, 7, 21, 11, 3, 4, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 
2, 10), Total = c(130, 274, 258, 419, 268, 210, 379, 244, 172, 
199, 87, 462, 211, 251, 382, 313, 509, 287, 253, 123, 92, 269, 
292, 313, 311, 361, 200, 261, 387, 261, 263, 293, 554, 587, 325, 
562, 434, 315, 521, 660, 661, 202, 204, 297, 549, 161, 368, 288, 
71, 341)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    filename = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Control = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Economic = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), ExternalVoices = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), JobsSkills = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), LegalStatus = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Modals = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Orign = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Sanctions = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Subjectivisms = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Verbs = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Total = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Thank you!

Comment: By Line Total do you mean by Row or by Collumn?

Comment: Hi i tried `examples_n <- lapply(1:ncol(examples), function(X) examples[,X]<-df[,X]*1000/colSums(examples)[X])` as you suggested, but I had the following error: `Error in df[, X] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`  thank you!

Comment: Try my new answer, I quickly deleted the one you tried.

Comment: Can you use the `dput()` command to share your `examples` as reproducible data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

examples %>% 
  mutate_at(
    vars(-matches("filename|LineTotal")),
    ~ .x * 1000 / LineTotal
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for (Where `example` is your data frame)

```
example[,2:ncol(example)] <- lapply(2:ncol(example), function(X) example[,X]*1000/sum(example[,X]))
```

Edit: One problem was that the first column in the dataframe had characters in it. This new code worked with the example data you provided.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it get me the following error:
`Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Can you use the `dput()` command to share your `examples` as reproducible data.

Comment: Thanks.
The example run, but there seems to be a problem in the calculation. If we get examples[1,1] and apply: (1*1000)/130, for example, teh result would be 7.692308 and not 14.92537 as it reesrults

Comment: I was dividing by the sun of elements in the collumn. I did not see that there was a collumn named “linetotal”

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

1) define column number of Line total

```
colname_tot = which(colnames(examples) == "LineTotal") -1
```

2) use apply to perfrom this operation on every row

```
examples = rbind(examples[, 1], as.data.frame(t(apply(examples[, -1], 1, function(x) {x = x*1000/x[colname_tot]})))
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks. But I had the following error:
'Error in x * 1000 : non-numeric argument to binary operator'

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Please double check your answer before posting and make sure it is reproducible. For instance you can output the few lines of the example table as a comment.

Comment: Sorry did not see the first column! As it is not numeric this would not work so you have to bind this column later with the rest of the dataframe

Comment: I edited my answer now, should work with the code you provided